# Application of Runge's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, approximation, self-learning

**Runge's theorem** states:

> Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb C$ and let $S\subset \overline{\mathbb C}\setminus K$, such that $S$ contains at least one
>   point in each connected component of $\overline{\mathbb C}\setminus K$. Then any function holomorphic in an open set containing $K$ can be
>   uniformly approximated by rational functions whose poles lie in $S$.

I want to solve the following exercise:

> Prove that there is a sequence $\{p_k\}_{k=1}^\infty $ of polynomials
>   such that : $$\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty }p_k(z)=\begin{cases}1 &,Re(z)>0\\0&,Re(z)=0\\-1&,Re(z)<0\end{cases}$$

I think we should find a sequence of holomorphic functions which converges to the desired function, and then approximate each function in the sequence by a polynomial ( which was its poles at $\infty $ , therefore Runge's theorem applies) .
Any hints would be appreciated. Maybe try something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $U_n = \{z: n \geq Re(z) \geq \frac{1}{n}, |Im(z)| \leq n\}$, $V_n = \{z: -n \leq Re(z) \leq \frac{-1}{n}, |Im(z)| \leq n\}$. Let $f_n: U_n \cup V_n \cup [-in, in] \to \mathbb{C}$ be defined as $f_n(z) = 1$ for $z \in U_n$, $f_n(z) = 0$ for $z \in [-in, in]$, $f_n(z) = -1$ for $z \in V_n$. $f_n$ is holomorpic, and $K_n = U_n \cup V_n \cup [-in, in]$ is compact subset of a complex plane, and $\bar{\mathbb{C}} - K_n$ has only one component, so if we take $S = \{\infty\}$, there's a rational function $p_n$ that only has poles in $S$, such that $\sup_{z \in K_n} |f_n(z) - p_n(z)| < \frac{1}{n}$. As $p_n$ has only pole at infinity, it's a polynomial. It's easy to see that sequence $p_n$ satisfy the requirements, because each $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is in $K_n$ for all $n$ starting from some $n_0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have some notes: First of all, the set $K_n$ as you define it is not bounded, nor closed therefore **it is not compact**. Also, I think we cannot define a holomorphic function only on an isolated interval $[-in,in]$. **We need an open area**. Finally, taking $sup|f_n-p_n|$ you dont apply Runge's theorem since the theorem needs **a preset holomorphic function**, and not a sequence of functions. Please be more explicit if you apply silently some other thoughts, since I cannot derive the result...

Comment: Yeah, $K_n$ is actually not compact, sorry about that, I'll fix it. Your other concerns are not really problems: The fuction $f_n$, as defined on $K_n$, extends to a holomorphic function on some open neighbourhood of $K_n$. Also, when taking $p_n$ such that $\sup_{z \in K_n} |f_n(z) - p_n(z)| < \frac{1}{n}$, we apply the Runge theorem to the function $f_n$, which is holomorphic on (some open neighbourhood of) $K_n$. Runge theorem asserts that we can approximate $f_n$ by polynomials in the supremum norm on $K_n$.

Comment: Ok, now I got a better picture. Thank you very much for your response!

Comment: @xyzzyz How did you claim that $f_n$ was holomorphic?

Comment: @xyzzyz Is it because $f_n$ satisfy Cauchy Riemann equations?

Comment: You can extend $f_n$ to a function defined on an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ that is locally constant -- that is, constant on each connected component of its domain. Being holomorphic is a local condition, and constant functions are obviously holomorphic. Therefore, $f_n$ can be extended to a holomorphic function defined on an open set.